# Ищу бесплатный сервис для озвучивания текста

Tags: text-to-speech

Подскажите пожалуйста бесплатный сервис для озвучивания текста. Т.е. у меня есть тексты, хочу что бы они были озвучены. Желательно на JavaScript.

Comment: вам именно онлайн нужны?

Comment: Мне бы вообще без облаков и оффлайн. Но если таких нет, то главное условие - бесплатно.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно использовать [Wep Speech Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API), в частности [speechSynthesis](http://caniuse.com/#search=speechSynthesis)

```js
speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello мир'));
```

Comment: Классно. А русский он умеет произносить?